# Rails how to order column sum query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ranking presentation.
Recommend model has user and count.

```
rank / user_name / recommend_count 
1 / A / 4 
2 / B / 2  
3 / C / 1
```

code

```
  @top_recommenders = Array.new
  recommends = Recommend.group(:user_id).order("sum_count DESC").limit(10).sum(:count)
  recommends.each do |recommend|
    recommend = Recommend.where(user_id: recommend[0]).first
    recommend.count = recommend[1]
    @top_recommenders << recommend
  end
```

schema

```
create_table "recommends", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "recommender_id"
    t.integer "count"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["recommender_id"], name: "index_recommends_on_recommender_id"
  end
```

That worked, but is not perfect.
How to query group by 'user' and order 'sum_count'?

Comment: is sum_count a column in recommends table.
What is the schema of recommends table? Can you please update your question with recommends schema??

Comment: @Surya Hi, I updated schema :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@top_recommenders =  Recommend.select('recommends.*,SUM(count) as count_total').group(:user_id).order("count_total DESC").limit(10)
```

The sum of count will be stored in the query result as count_total.
If you need to store it as each recommend objects count, then map it as below.

```
@top_recommenders.map { |r| r.count = r.count_total }
```